# How to create black and white tv effect like IGTV in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, animation

I want to use starting of app as starting of black and white tv like at start of IGTV how can I do it in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a loading screen for IGTV creating it programmatically in flutter would be a lot of hard work. It would be easier to do it by using after effect or some gifs.

Comment: I dont want to do it programmatically I just want the logic and source gif or resource of aftereffects.

Comment: You could try dribble. You might find it there and for the logic part that is the same as other loading screens, you wait until the data is being loaded.

Comment: here is one link I found:  https://tenor.com/view/tv-old-glitch-no-signal-static-gif-17321108